# Javascriptexecutor is it detectable?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I'm using javascriptexecutor in Java with selenium and trying to figure out whether this is detectable by the webpage?

With Javascriptexecutor there seems to be some javascript being injected into the page, so I'm wondering if someone with a bigger brain than me can help me figure out whether these injections can be detected by the webpage they are being used on?

For instance, take the following code:

```
    JavascriptExecutor jsExec = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    jsExec.executeScript("document.getElementById('IdToScrollTo').scrollDown += 100");
```

This code did not originate on the page (scrollDown), so it has been injected. Could this be detected?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is detectable - any JS is. It is detectable by detecting whether the JS is modified in the page, on their side - so it is easily detectable.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15415240)

Comment: Ah ok I will elaborate.